# Ajax PHP Jquery - echo-ing back data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble bringing back data from my PHP file. I guess I don't really understand the data parameter of this jquery function so I just went off some tutorials.

Jquery

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {test: '1'},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        }
    })
```

Now from my understanding the `test:` declares the variable used in php and `1` is the value in that variable. But I'm not entirely sure...

Here's my PHP

```
$item1 = $_POST['test'];

    echo $item1;
```

Now it's just supposed to alert that value so I know it is at least returning something but in the alert it's just blank so I'm losing the value somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use `$_REQUEST` it will handle both the `GET` and `POST`

```
$item1 = $_REQUEST['test'];
```

by default ajax request is `GET` type, either specify expilicitly the `type` like

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'test.php',
        type:'POST'
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {test: '1'},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        }
    })
```

or use `$_GET` like

```
item1 = $_GET['test'];

    echo $item1;
```

Comment: awwww man staring me in the face the whole time. Good to know it's GET by default though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**The correct way:**

```
<?php
$change = array('key1' => 'blabla', 'key2' => '12432rr424234');
echo json_encode($change);
?>
```

Then the jquery script:

```
<script>
$.get("location.php", function(data){
  var mydata= $.parseJSON(data);
  var art1 = mydata.key1;  // <-----------  access the element
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is work for me**

ajax code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script>
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'test.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: {latitude: '7.15588546', longitude: '81.5659984458'},
                        success: function (response)
                        {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

php code (test.php)

```
<?php

$lat = $_REQUEST['latitude'];
$lon = $_REQUEST['longitude'];

echo 'latitude- '.$lat . ', longitude- ' . $lon;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add POST method:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        data: {test: '1'},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put the method POST/GET by which you are sending the data to your php file.

```
$.ajax(
    {        
        type:'POST',        
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {test: '1'},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 just add "type" POST or GET     

 //example
 $.ajax(
{
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {test: '1'},
    success: function(data)
    {
        window.alert(data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get information from the php file, I don't think the data field is required. Here is what I have.

```
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'response.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType:'text',
                    success: function(data){
                        window.alert(data);
                    }
                }
```

and as far as the php goes..

```
<?php
   echo "1";
   echo "2";
   echo "3";
   echo "4";
   echo "5";
   echo "6";
   echo "7";
   echo "8";
?>
```

[Alert box on execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H10Kq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling on this for a while, my issue wasn't on the js but in php script : error reporting was set to E_ALL - which apparently blocks it from returning data to the AJAX call. My guess is it prints notices before the final echo and blocks it all. Weird thing is it didn't print me any notice in the logs i set up to get to the bottom of this.

Changed it to E_ERROR and now works like a charm.